# Why did Shouko change her hair style?

Tags: koe-no-katachi

This is the first time Shouko change her hair style to ponytail. What's the reason ?

[image]

Comment: I get the impression that you'll get the context of it if you read the rest of the chapter.  One thing to note: *tsuki ga kirei*, or "The moon is beautiful", was an old way of confessing.

Comment: did you mean this [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsuki_ga_Kirei) ?

Comment: No... The saying is from the 1800s, or rather a very long time ago, when Japanese people couldn't really express "love" as we in the modem era understand it.

Comment: If you scroll down to the "other uses" of the phrase in that article, you'll see why it's considered a confession of love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the answer in Volume 4, chapter 24 ( **read from right to left** or look at the page number )

**Volume 4, chapter 24, page 6,7,8**

[image: page 8][image: page 7][image: page 6]

Ishida realized that what Kawaii do to her appearance is clearly the same with Shouko at **chapter 23**. It's pretty obvious that Kawaii like Mashiba.

So The reason why Kawaii change her appearance is because **she want to look attractive in front of Mashiba**. It's same with Shouko case.

It's just my speculation but from the interpreter of the story at chapter 23 said that **Shouko want to look attractive** ( she want to looks different ) in front of Ishida, and after that he confession to Ishida but it didn't go so well. But Ishida still didn't know what shouko feel toward him.

Comment: You *should* explain it with the text. Text is the main tool for the explanation, while images (and external links) are considered as a supporting tool. The reason is, text is indexable/searchable, while image is not. Your answer should stand alone as if there's no image/link.